# Does anyone know how to convert seconds data into minutes in Data Studio?

Tags: postgresql, calculated-field

Does anyone know how to convert seconds data into minutes in Data Studio?

I tried Minute()

Comment: You can simply divide the value by 60.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PostgreSQL function [`JUSTIFY_INTERVAL()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-datetime.html)

```
SELECT JUSTIFY_INTERVAL('1200 SECOND');
```

Result:

```
justify_interval
00:20:00
```

See the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=e0006a61cd37d79e5c70cfad95a1acbc).